# Nested tables in SQL Server Reporting Services without using Subreports

Tags: ssrs-2008, xtrareport

I'd like to achieve somthing similar to the nested products and orders tables shown in this [XtraReports example](http://demos.devexpress.com/XtraReportsDemos/ReportTypes/MasterDetail.aspx) using SQL Server Reporting Services.

Also I'd prefer to do it without using Subreports.

Comment: IMO you don't actually need to make use of subreport, instead you could make use of List containing Tablix with row group to prepare such report.